# SwiftUI app doesn't run when supporting iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

App was working fine when the deployment target was 15.2, but then I needed to change the deployment target to iOS 13 to support more devices. Still works fine on iOS 14+, but it crashes with exception `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`, when it runs on iOS 13 on the simulator. Console shows no debug information:

```
CoreSimulator 802.6 - Device: iPhone 11 (iOS 13.0) (6CCC2B89-002B-4E83-8175-C244984BFC46) - Runtime: iOS 13.0 (17A577) - DeviceType: iPhone 11
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9
```

Here are the related segments of the WeatherApp.swift file code along with a screenshot of the error:

```
@main
struct WeatherAppWrapper {
    static func main() {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            WeatherApp.main()
        }
        else {
            UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(SceneDelegate.self))
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct WeatherApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @StateObject var loginStatus = UserLoginStatus()
    
    @available(iOS 14.0, *)
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView{
                if Methods.UserAccount.getFromUserDefaults()["username"] != nil {
                    MainView(loggedIn: $loginStatus.loggedIn)
                    LoginView(username: "", password: "", loggedIn: $loginStatus.loggedIn)
                } else {
                    LoginView(username: "", password: "", loggedIn: $loginStatus.loggedIn)
                    MainView(loggedIn: $loginStatus.loggedIn)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

            //Some app-specific setup code
            ...
            
            return true
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

```
class UserLoginStatus: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loggedIn: Bool {
        didSet {
            print("The value of loggedIn changed from \(oldValue) to \(loggedIn)")
        }
    }
    
    init () {
        loggedIn = false
    }
}

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    @StateObject var loginStatus = UserLoginStatus()

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let mainView = MainView(loggedIn: $loginStatus.loggedIn)
        let loginView = LoginView(username: "", password: "", loggedIn: $loginStatus.loggedIn)

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            
            if Methods.UserAccount.getFromUserDefaults()["username"] != nil {
                window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: mainView)
            } else {
                window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: loginView)
            }
            
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    
}
```

---

[image]

Also, here is a screenshot of the Info.plist file, specifically expanding the related area:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StateObject` is available from SwiftUI 2.0 (iOS 14) and is designed to work in View, not in class (like `SceneDelegate`)

For provided scenario a possible solution is to use `logicState` as just property at top level (in delegate or main view), but inject it completely into child views (instead of just binding) and observe it internally.

So it should look like

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var loginStatus = UserLoginStatus() // << just hold here

// ...

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let mainView = MainView(loginStatus: loginStatus) // << here !!
```

and

```
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var loginStatus: UserLoginStatus   // << injected here

// ...
}
```

similar can be done in `WeatherApp`

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject), `StateObject` is only available on iOS 14+.

Comment: How can i do the same using a different approach?

Comment: IMO, it's a topic for entirely different question: How to implement this and that behavior in Swift and iOS 13+. Whereas, this question specifically is about finding the reason of the crash. However, as I can see, Asperi walked an extra mile and already gave you a good hint.